# Is there an auxiliary formula for cosine and tan?

Tags: trigonometry

I'm currently studying triangle trigonometry and I was taught the auxiliary formulae for half angles of sine, cosine and tangent, which are

$$ \sin {\frac{A}{2}} = \sqrt{\frac{(s-b)(s-c)}{bc}} $$

$$ \cos {\frac{A}{2}} = \sqrt{\frac{s(s-a)}{bc}} $$

$$ \tan {\frac{A}{2}} = \sqrt{\frac{(s-b)(s-c)}{(s-a)}} $$

Where $A$, $B$, $C$ stand for the angles of any triangle, $a$, $b$, $c$ stand for the sides opposite those angles, $\triangle {}$ stands for the area of a triangle and $s$ stands for the semi perimeter of the triangle.

I derived the formula for sine on my own, but I'm not able to get a clean formula for either cosine or tangent

$$ \sin A  = \frac{2 \triangle} {bc} $$

The formula should also contain some of the following terms: the sides of a triangle, angles of a triangle, area of the triangle and semi-perimeter, otherwise, it won't be applicable in the problems I am given

Thanks for reading!

Comment: You want expressions for $\cos A$ and $\tan A$ , like the one available for $\sin A$, is that right?

Comment: Yes, that is right

Comment: You can use ```\sin ```, ```\cos ``` for better formatting (remember to put a space after these).

Comment: These classical formulas were useful for computation with a table of logarithms, because they involve mainly products and divisions. There are many other trigonometric formulas, it would be simpler to show the kind of problem you have, instead of asking for a specific formula that may, or may not, be optimal. Note, by the way, that you may face numerical problems: for instance, for small angles, sine and tangent are usually preferred, because the cosine curve is flat near the origin.

Comment: I also removed from the question the unnecessary formulas for B and C, that can be found by cyclic permutation of the formula for A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you are looking for following formulas:

$$\tan \frac A2=\frac r{s-a}$$

$$r=\frac{\triangle}s=\sqrt{\frac{(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}s}$$

Answer (score 1):

For the cosine,
$$ c^2 = a^2 + b^2 - 2ab\cos C $$
which simplifies to
$$\cos C = \frac{a^2+b^2-c^2}{2ab}  $$

For tangent you can calculate as,
$$\tan C=\frac{\sin C}{\cos C}$$
Or you can use the double angle formula:
$$ \tan A = \frac{2\tan\left(\frac{A}{2}\right)}{1-\tan^2\left(\frac{A}{2}\right)}$$

Comment: Using Cyclicity you can derive for other Angles A,B,C